# Database design: when to use a seperated column for a list of strings and when to use database entities/records

Tags: database, hibernate, database-design

I want to save sport team names in my database. At a later point i need to find these teams by a given String which sometimes not match exactly the saved String in the database.
Im using mariadb (but could switch over to another free rdbms) as underlying database and hibernate.

For example: I save a record in my database with the name

```
C.A. Tigre
```

Now i want to be able to find this certain record by searching with

```
CA Tigre
```

or

```
C. A. Tigre
```

or

```
C A Tigre
```

and so on. The database will contain more than 100k teams and i expect to have a average of 5 aliases for every team so it should be more or less a kind of generic approach.

My first idea was to use/implement a database fuzzy search but im not sure if this will be enough. Another idea which came into my mind was additionally to use aliases for the names where i know which will be used for a search.

Given the approach with aliases which i prefer at the moment im not sure how i should persist theses aliases. I could save them in the certain database record in a new column and use a seperated String list or i could save them as a own record (parent/childs or something like this).

Performance wise im having at the moment the impression the seperated String list could be the best option compared to save (and fetch for search) every alias as a one record but this is just a feeling.

Does anybody have experience in this or does anybody know any best practises for this use case?

Answer (score 0):

I would create an alias table with a foreign key reference back to the team table. Then Put an index on the alias name column. You can search on the alias name, returning all matches, then via the FK you have have your relationship back to the actual team name for the alias matches.